# Intellij - Unexpected wildcard mark as problem

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, warnings, unbounded-wildcard

We moved from VS Code to use Intellij Ultimate latest version, and we have existing code using Java 8:

```
private Map<Integer, Queue<Condition<?>>> loadConditions(Map<Integer, Condition<?>> conditions) {

Map<Integer, Queue<Condition<?>>> conditions = new HashMap<>();
...
Queue<Condition<?>> conditionsSet;
...
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("ID");
                int conditionId = rs.getInt("CONDITION_ID");
                conditionsSet = conditions.getOrDefault(id, new PriorityQueue<Condition<?>>(Comparator.comparingInt(Condition<?>::getPriority).reversed()));
                conditionsSet.add(conditions.get(conditionId));
                conditions.put(id, conditionsSet);
            }
```

Intellij in Problems tab (and underline in code) mark `Condition<?>::getPriority` with red as `Unexpected wildcard`

The code compiles (Java 8) and works, How can I reduce its severity to warning? I don't find `Unexpected wildcard` in Inspections window

**EDIT**

If I copy line (below) to a method it is marked as compilation error also in VS code, but still compiles

```
private void name() {
    new PriorityQueue<Condition<?>>(Comparator.comparingInt(Condition<?>::getPriority));
}
```

Problem:

```
The type Condition<capture#14-of ?> does not define getPriority(Condition<capture#1-of ?>) that is applicable hereJava(603979903)
```

Condition Class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Condition<T> {
    // fields
    private int priority; 
}
```

Comment: Hello, is "condition" a variable or a parameter? How "rs" is defined? Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho `Condition` is an object, `rs` is `ResultSet`

Comment: Can you please create an issue at the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA providing a sample project? Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho see my edit

Comment: regarding the "moved to" - from where? If not from another IDEA version or edition, did you check the Java language level in the "Project structure..." dialog (in the File menu)? Also check it for all modules - could differ from the project default.
And for sake of completeness: you are working with `java.util.PriorityQueue<E>` I suppose?
A [mre] really would be helpful to reproduce it in our installations.

Comment: @cyberbrain from vs code,java 8 in all modules,java.util.PriorityQue

Comment: Could reproduce it, but also didn't find a solution in the configuration of IDEA - probably a bug? For now also found only the solution of rewriting the code to a lambda instead of a method reference, as @Eskander did in his answer. (A decompile of the compiled class of the method reference also shows a lambda function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

```
conditionsSet = conditions.getOrDefault(id, new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt((Condition<?> condition) -> condition.getPriority()).reversed()));
```

If you want use method reference you should use this:

```
conditionsSet = conditions.getOrDefault(id, new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt((ToIntFunction<Condition<?>>) Condition::getPriority).reversed()));
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but why Intellij show error when using the method reference?

Comment: Added another solution using the method reference to the answer